# Configuring WSO2ESB to return replies without chunked encoding

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have read the posts about adding a property to disable chunked encoding, but cannot figure out how to apply that to the "frontend" as opposed to the service being proxied.  My service is running in GlassFish and is able to accept chunked requests and emit chunked replies.  I have disabled chunking on glassfish, but it seems that wso2esb is still using this encoding when a client, in this case a Microsoft .NET application using WSE3.0 to support security makes a request specifying HTTP 1.1.

Is there a way to force the reply to this client to not use chunk encoding ?

My proxy service description is included below.

Thanks in advance,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following.

```
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2" />  <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
```

Please follow this [blog post](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-chunking-wso2-esb-proxy.html).